# phonegap push notification not working on iPhone

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I am working on Ionic app in which I have used phonegap push plugin but it's not working. When app install first time on iPhone it shows the notification permission pop-up then after click on allow button nothing happening, also I am not able to trace the exact error.

Comment: Are you actually sending the notification to the phone?

Comment: no I am not sending. it's not registering for push notification when I click on notification permission allow button

Comment: If you allow to receive notification manually, I mean in phone settings , it works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a certificate with permission to send push notification? 
Do you enabled the push notification capability before you build with xcode?

Check the payload that your are sending. This payload works for me:

```
{
    "registration_ids":["device token"],
    "content_available": true,
    "notification" : {
        "force-start": "1",
        "content-available": "1",
        "no-cache": "1",
        "body":"Test" ,
        "title" : "Test",
        "sound" : "default" ,
        "icon":"default",
        "badge": 5
    },
    "priority":10
}
```

Add badge only when you want to display the badge on your app icon